# "JetBrains IDE Support" is debugging the browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, liveedit

There..

I cannot hide `"JetBrains IDE Support" is debugging the browser` banner in chrome 79+

As `Enable Silent Debugging` in Chrome flags is missing in chrome 79

Comment: It's a bug, https://crbug.com/1034858, you can run chrome binary with `--silent-debugger-extension-api` command line.

Comment: It still now working.. I used by Command Line and also edited the shortcut target still not working

Comment: 1) When editing the command line you need to make sure all chrome `processes` (not `applications`) were terminated in the task manager. 2) Depending on how you start Chrome during debugging you may need to alter the command line in a different place.